# How to mark script as failed but without aborting execution of current test case in Selenium?

Tags: java

How to mark script as failed but without aborting execution of current test case in Selenium?

```
@Test
public void testCase() { 
  System.out.println("line 1 printed"); 
  Assert.assertTrue(false);
  System.out.println("i want to execute this line after failure");
}
```

Comment: so is there in function or class available instead of assert?'

Comment: If you are using TestNG you could look into SoftAsserts

Comment: @Aniket - are you using junit OR testng? please add the relative tag to the question

Comment: @Aniket please mark an answer here if applicable

Answer (score 1):

Using `test-ng`

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

@Test
public void testCase() { 
    System.out.println("line 1 printed");
    softAssert.assertTrue(true); 
    softAssert.assertEquals("India", "US");
    softAssert.assertTrue(false);
    System.out.println("i want to execute this line after failure");
    softAssert.assertAll();
}
```

---

I doubt `junit` still does not provide such capability.